# error with initiating varibles within an awk command in bash

Tags: bash, awk, ansi-escape

### Goal

I want to iterate over my file with awk which works fine, but when tried to insert my `COLOR` and `WHITE` variables.

I realized that I would have to first initialize it within the awk
command like so: `-v COLOR="${COLOR}"` and `WHITE="${WHITE}"`. Yet when I did so I started getting the following error:

```
awk: warning: escape sequence `\e' treated as plain `e'
awk: cmd. line:1: WHITE=\e[1;37m
awk: cmd. line:1:       ^ backslash not last character on line
awk: cmd. line:1: WHITE=\e[1;37m
awk: cmd. line:1:       ^ syntax error
```

### Full Code

bash.sh

```
WHITE="\e[1;37m"
COLOR="\e[1;31m"

awk -v COLOR="${COLOR}" WHITE="${WHITE}"  awk -v COLOR="$COLOR" -v WHITE="$WHITE" '
    {
        system("sleep 0.1")
        print "    ("COLOR" NR "WHITE") " $0
    }
' settings.tropx
```

the settings.tropx file:

```
some setting
some other setting
set ting
another setting
```

### Final

What is this error referring to and how can I fix it?

Comment: Use `\033` instead of `\e`, e.g. `WHITE="\033[1;37m"` Simple check: `awk 'BEGIN { color="\033[1;34m"; nocolor="\033[0m"; print color "hello" nocolor }` -- will print `"hello"` in {blue} if on a VT100 compatible terminal.

Comment: Here is a color-check for you `awk 'BEGIN { for (i=30; i<38; i++) { color="\033[1;"i"m"; nocolor="\033[0m"; print i "  " color "hello" nocolor }}'`

Comment: Don't forget to output `nocolor="\033[0m"` to reset the output to the default when you are done outputting color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would you please try:

```
#!/bin/bash

WHITE=$'\e[1;37m'
COLOR=$'\e[1;31m'

awk -v COLOR="$COLOR" -v WHITE="$WHITE" '
    {
        system("sleep 0.1")
        print "    ("COLOR NR WHITE") " $0
    }
' settings.tropx
```

We need to use ANSI quoting `$'..'` with bash to include an escape sequence. But if you do not have a specific reason to use `-v` mechanism, you can also say:

```
awk '
    BEGIN {COLOR="\033[1;31m"; WHITE="\033[1;37m"}
    {
        system("sleep 0.1")
        print "    ("COLOR NR WHITE") " $0
    }
' settings.tropx
```

Comment: I do need to the -v mech. as the two values might change to different colors when I think so

Comment: i got this error:```awk: warning: escape sequence `\e' treated as plain `e'
    (e[1;31m1e[1;37m) Debug Mode : OFF | (ON)
    (e[1;31m2e[1;37m) Animations : (ALL) | SOME | NONE
    (e[1;31m3e[1;37m) Default Scripts : (SHOW) | HIDE```

Comment: Did you change the bash variable assignments as shown in my answer? `WHITE="\e[1;37m"` will not work.

Comment: i have these rn : `WHITE="\033[1;37m"

```COLOR="\033[1;31m"

```

Comment: il changeit right away

Answer (score 0):

even if your original shell variables use the `\e` notation, u can use awk to fix it :

```
 __w__="${WHITE}" \
 __c__="${COLOR}" \
 mawk '
 BEGIN {  FS = "\\\\\e"
         OFS = "\33" 
       $(ORS = "") = ENVIRON["__w__"]"1"ENVIRON["__c__"]
 print $!(NF = NF) }'



0000000         993090331       829241139       993090331         7156019
         033   [   1   ;   3   7   m   1 033   [   1   ;   3   1   m    
          033 133 061 073 063 067 155 061 033 133 061 073 063 061 155    
         esc   [   1   ;   3   7   m   1 esc   [   1   ;   3   1   m    
           27  91  49  59  51  55 109  49  27  91  49  59  51  49 109    
           1b  5b  31  3b  33  37  6d  31  1b  5b  31  3b  33  31  6d    

0000017
```